# placing a div element before another div that is centered

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to put a div element right before an element that is already centered? The already centered div element would have to line up with the div element on top. I am trying to accomplish below described in the picture

```
           --------
           |      |
           |  1   |
           --------
     ----  --------
     |   | |      |
     |3  | |  2   |
      ---  --------
```

div blocks 1 and 2 would line up on top of each other. I can do this doing a simple margin: 0 auto;

```
.div1 .div2{
  margin: 0 auto
}
```

However, I am having trouble setting div block 3 right before 2. A float:left on div block 3 did not work either. Is there any way to insert div block 3 before 2 while keeping the margin: 0 auto property on div block 2. Any help or pointers would be appreciated

Comment: position:absolute on div3 ?

Comment: I thought about this but wouldn't that have a negative effect on the responsiveness of the div?

Comment: it will depend on how you want the responsiveness to be and how your HTML structure is

Answer (score 1):

I'm advocating for CSS Grid and `grid-template-areas`. In case you're unfamiliar with the syntax, the `.` represents an empty cell in the grid.

```css
.container { 
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  grid-template-areas: ". one"
                       "three two";
}
.container div {
  border: 1px dashed;
  padding: 4px;
}

.div1 {
  grid-area: one;
}

.div2 {
  grid-area: two;
  justify-self: flex-start;  
}

.div3 {
  grid-area: three;
  justify-self: flex-end;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">div 2</div>
  <div class="div3">div 3</div>
</div>
```

**Update**

I've adjusted the grid items to behave more like you requested in the comments. I removed `justify-content: center` from the grid parent, which lets the grid items expand to the parent container. Then I used `justify-self` to pin `div2` and `div3` to the center.

Comment: thank you for the response. I tried it out and it works great. I gave div1 a width of 1020px and a max-width: 100%. When I minimize the browser, div1 element is not responsive and does not change with the screen size. Is there a work around this?

Comment: @hello I adjusted the grid so that `div1` spans the maximum width and `div2` and `div3` stay in the center. I wasn't able to adjust `div1` to have a `width` of `1020px` while remaining constrained with the parent grid container.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a solution based on CSS grid like below:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:1fr auto 1fr;
}

.container > div {
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:200px;
  outline:1px solid;
  grid-column:2;
}
.container > div:last-child {
  grid-column:1;
  grid-row:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

Another idea with flexbox:

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.container > div {
  min-height:50px;
  min-width:200px;
  outline:1px solid;
}
.container > div:first-child {
  order:-2;
  margin:auto; 
}
.container > div:last-child {
  order:-1;
  margin:0;
  flex:1;
}

/*to create break line*/
.container:before {
  content:"";
  order:-1;
  flex-basis:100%;
}

/*to have the same as 3*/
.container:after {
  content:"";
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```

You can also consider positioning:

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
}

.container > div:not(:last-child) {
  min-height:50px;
  max-width:200px;
  outline:1px solid;
  margin:auto;
}

.container > div:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  width:calc((100% - 200px)/2);
  min-height:50px;
  outline:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
</div>
```